# After importing Database on host my joomla site dose not worked well

Tags: database, joomla2.5

I have a web site in Joomla, it is in local host and it works with no problem.

After I imported Database on host it doesn't  work well! 
Menus and sub menus links do not work!

Please see my site and click on the menus, http://alborzyoga.ir
I checked source code, it is OK and I think problem is with DB.

Answer (score 1):

Mina: For future posts try to do better formatting, otherwise you'll get down-votes.

Please follow the steps from [Joomla forum.](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=187461)

I guess you are missing some folders. For the start, check "administrator" and "components" folders and sub-folders in your local machine and compare it with folder tree on the server

UPDATE: Did you just restore MySQL database? Was there any upgrades in your local version? If so, it could be also a problem with PHP version.

UPDATE2: If your menu is not working after changing server, you should check your URL. If you have absolute path, change it to relative.

Comment: thank you Kenan,at the first there is a question, Mysql version in local host is 5.6 and in host is 5.0 ...Is it possible the problem is with mysql version??

Comment: Hmmm, it could be a problem: take a look at this link: http://docs.joomla.org/Technical_requirements - for Joomla 2.5 the minimum version is 5.0.4.

Comment: Server version is 5.0.5, how could I check  php version?

Comment: First, can you explain what is "imported Database"? Did you just restore DB or move complete site?

Comment: OK, looking at your site... which part is not working? Sorry I can't understand the content (I guess it's Farsi).

Comment: yes, it is Persian.. menu is not working:( it must link to their pages , source cod is true but it is not worked